# How to remove '+ off' from the end of string?

Tags: r

Similar to [R - delete last two characters in string if they match criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281718/r-delete-last-two-characters-in-string-if-they-match-criteria) except I'm trying to get rid of the special character '+' as well. I also attached a picture of my output.

When I attempt to use the escape command of '+', I get an error message saying

```
Error: '\+' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\\s\+"
```

[image: Image of output with '+ off' showing]

Comment: Use [+] instead

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, `+` is a metacharacter in regex so it needs to be escaped. `\+` escapes that character, but `\`, itself, is a special character in R character strings so it, too, needs to be escaped. This is an R requirement, not a regex requirement.

This means that, instead of `'\+'`, you need to write `'\\+'`.